# Count IF one of two criteria are met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am struggling to work out the solution to what should be as simple problem in excel.

I have a column which contains several letter characters (C, D, P, R, S). Each cell can contain any combination of these.

How can I count the number of cells which contain either: S, C, or S & C. Keep in mind, that if it contains both S & C, I still only want to to be counted once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the column containing the data is "A", create following formula in column B:

```
=OR(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("s",A:A,1))),NOT(ISERROR(FIND("c",A:A,1))))
```

Then you can get your answer by using following formula (that you can put in any other cell , say in cell C1)

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,TRUE)
```

Note: FIND is case sensitive. If you want to do case insensitive search, use SEARCH function.

Comment: Thanks for this - quick addition. Can I just add another NOT(ISERROR(FIND("r",A:A,1))) if I wanted to add R?

Comment: Yes, of course! You can add as many conditions to the OR clause for rest of the characters.

Answer (score 2):

The [SIGN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SIGN-function-cfaaf798-9b34-4569-955c-a74a523a7c4a) can convert multiple results from an [ISNUMBER](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-490afee4-fd91-4839-89d4-1257a21b4e25) and [FIND¹](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-function-06213F91-B5BE-4544-8B0B-2FD5A775436F) to simply being greater than zero. [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) provides the cyclic calculation to add the results from each row.

[image: count_multiples]

The formula in F4 is,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN(ISNUMBER(FIND("C", D2:D9))+ISNUMBER(FIND("S", D2:D9))))
```

---

¹ <sub>The [FIND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-function-06213F91-B5BE-4544-8B0B-2FD5A775436F) is case-sensitive. The [SEARCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3) is not.</sub>